# tfs build does not complete although all tasks completed

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a TFS build that keep going for ever although all tasks have been completed. 
I have included  in all Targets. 
I get the last message, but the build is still running.

Comment: Will you get any error message at last? Have you customize your build definition? Check event log in Event Viewer to see whether there is anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. My Build deploys multiple applications to multiple server profiles. as a pre-deployment and post-deployment actions, the build used MSBuild Exec tasks to run batch files that use PsExec on remote servers. 
One of these batch files wasn't finishing. And since the Exec task used 
ContinueOnError='true' Timeout='5000' MSBuild was moving on to the next task until it finishes everything and then wait on that batch file process to finish. 
When I connect to the TFS server and kill this batch file process, the build finishes.

Later I fixed the hanging issue in that batch file.